# How to dynamically update service variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a date value defined in a service which is used by all of my controllers (ie when a site loads the value is initialized and sent to all controllers using it), Now I want to be able update this variable from all controllers dynamically. i.e. When a date is updated from one of the controllers to this service - an updated value should be sent(initialized again) to all the controllers. There by allowing me to have a common date throughout my website.

AnyHelp ?!

here's my code for service and one of the controllers using it and updating(which does not work though) :

```js
appOne.factory('dates',function($rootScope){
        $rootScope.startDateCal   = moment().subtract(127, 'days');
        $rootScope.endDateCal   = moment();
 });
 
 appOne.controller("ControllerOne",['$scope','$http','apiUrl','$state','$timeout','$interval','dates', function($rootScope, $http,apiUrl,$state,
$timeout,$interval,dates){
    $scope = this;
     
    var apiURL = apiUrl ;


$scope.cb= function(start, end){
    // console.log(start.format('D MMMM YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('D MMMM YYYY'));

        $('#dateRange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        startDateCal = start;
        endDateCal = end;
        if($('#sel_deviceType').length){
            type = $('#sel_deviceType').val();
        } else {
            type = "A";
        }
        $scope.loadChart(parseInt(start/1000),parseInt(end/1000), appKey, type);
                 
    }
     

     $('#dateRange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
                      // trying to update the service variable 
                            $rootScope.startDateCal = moment.utc(startDateCal).format('LL');;
                            $rootScope.endDateCal = moment.utc(endDateCal).format('LL');;
    });   

    $scope.cb($rootScope.startDateCal,$rootScope.endDateCal);

    $('#dateRange').daterangepicker({
    ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment()],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
       'This Week': [moment().startOf('week'), moment().endOf('week')],
       'Last Week': [moment().subtract(1, 'week').startOf('week'), moment().subtract(1, 'week').endOf('week')],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
},
locale: {
     format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
     applyLabel: "Select"
},
startDate: $rootScope.startDateCal,
endDate: $rootScope.endDateCal
}, $scope.cb);

)}




appOne.controller("ControllerTwo",['$scope','$http','apiUrl','$state','$timeout','$interval','dates', function($rootScope, $http,apiUrl,$state,
$timeout,$interval,dates){
    $scope = this;
     
    var apiURL = apiUrl ;


$scope.cb= function(start, end){
    // console.log(start.format('D MMMM YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('D MMMM YYYY'));

        $('#dateRange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        startDateCal = start;
        endDateCal = end;
        if($('#sel_deviceType').length){
            type = $('#sel_deviceType').val();
        } else {
            type = "A";
        }
        $scope.loadChart(parseInt(start/1000),parseInt(end/1000), appKey, type);
                 
    }
     

     $('#dateRange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
                      // trying to update the service variable 
                            $rootScope.startDateCal = moment.utc(startDateCal).format('LL');;
                            $rootScope.endDateCal = moment.utc(endDateCal).format('LL');;
    });   

    $scope.cb($rootScope.startDateCal,$rootScope.endDateCal);

    $('#dateRange').daterangepicker({
    ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment()],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
       'This Week': [moment().startOf('week'), moment().endOf('week')],
       'Last Week': [moment().subtract(1, 'week').startOf('week'), moment().subtract(1, 'week').endOf('week')],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
},
locale: {
     format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
     applyLabel: "Select"
},
startDate: $rootScope.startDateCal,
endDate: $rootScope.endDateCal
}, $scope.cb);

)}
```

```html
<div id="dateRange"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a easy way to do that first you create an object in your service like

```
var date={};
date.currdate=value;
```

then you return this date in service, and you can use this date across all the controllers and you can also change or update date value dynamically.

Comment: I would try it but would that do things dynamically ?? will it resend the updated value to all the controllers ?

Comment: and how would I refer to this object in controller - uptill now I used to refer it as '$rootScope.variablename = value'

Comment: create a getter in the service that will be returning this object.